# Windows - FFmpeg - How to map a jpg file to video stream 0:0 and include only audio stream 0:2 and not stream 0:1 and 0:2 together

Tags: windows, batch-file, encoding, ffmpeg, audio-streaming

I am trying to write a batch script that begins by extracting a thumbnail "Cover.jpg" from an mkv video. My end goal is to have this script recursively loop a folder full of videos to encode them all in one go.

```
:: create cover art jpg
for %%G in (*.mkv) do (
%FF% -hide_banner -ss 30 -y -i "%%G" -vframes 1 -an Cover.jpg
)
```

Then I am trying to encode the 4K mkv video that I got the jpg thumbnail from to 1920x1080 resolution instead of it's native 4K to make it easier to play back on my home plex server.

I have surround sound 6 channel speaker system so I want to take audio stream 0:2 which is Dolby DTS 6 channel and save some HDD space by converting it to `-c:a ac3 -b:a 640k -ac 6`.

I have gotten stuck because I can achieve everything I want except I keep encoding 2 of the 4 audio streams available in the end. I only want to keep 1 audio stream to maximize my space savings.

Here is the entire script so far.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
prompt $g
color 0a

pushd "%~dp0"

set FF=C:\MAB\local64\bin-video\ffmpeg.exe
set TITLE=MOVIETITLE

:: create cover art jpg file
for %%G in (*.mkv) do (
%FF% -hide_banner -ss 30 -y -i "%%G" -vframes 1 -an Cover.jpg
)

:: run ffmpeg x265
for %%I in (*.mkv) do (
set fname="%%~nxI"
set fout="%%~nI-temp.mkv"
call :runff !fname! !fout!
del /s /q *.jpg
pause
goto:eof
)

:runff
%FF% -ss 0 ^
-y ^
-i "%~1" ^
-attach "Cover.jpg" ^
-map_metadata 0 ^
-map_chapters 0 ^
-metadata title="%TITLE%" ^
-map 0:0 -metadata:s:v:0 language=eng ^
-map 0:2 -metadata:s:a:0 language=eng -metadata:s:a:0 title="Surround 5.1 (DTS)" ^
-map 0:3 -metadata:s:s:0 language=eng -metadata:s:s:0 title="English" -metadata:s:t:0 filename="Cover.jpg" -metadata:s:t:0 mimetype="image/jpeg" ^
-c:v libx265 -preset medium ^
-x265-params crf=18:qcomp=0.8:aq-mode=1:aq_strength=1.0:qg-size=16:psy-rd=0.7:psy-rdoq=5.0:rdoq-level=1:merange=44 ^
-c:a ac3 -b:a 640k -ac 6 ^
-t 3 ^
"%~2"
exit /b
```

Here are the output logs. `https://pastebin.com/hVMy3VJW`

You can see towards the bottom that it is encoding both audio streams.

Any ideas guys?

Comment: Add -report and share report for conversion of one file.

Comment: check out the logs as requested. thank you for taking some time with this to help me. `https://pastebin.com/hVMy3VJW`

Comment: Your input has 1 video and 3 audio streams. You're mapping 0:2 and 0:3 both of which are audio, hence 2 audio streams in the output.

Comment: I saw that. I thought for some reason I needed to include a third stream to make the thumbnail merge with the video. How exactly would you do that?

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

Update: 06.21.20
-Improved variable name output method.
-Formatting changes

Instructions: Create a batch file with this code and place it in the folder with the files you are wanting to change. You must change the `ff` variable to point to your own `ffmpeg.exe` file if it is not on the system path. This only works with `.mkv` videos.

This script by default will erase all audio channels except for the first one and replace it with aac surround 6 channel encoding. It will name the channel the same name as the input file. The original file will still be there in case you make an error and need to retry.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
color 0a

pushd "%~dp0"

set ff=C:\MAB\local64\bin-video\ffmpeg.exe

set sec=30
set fjpeg=cover.jpg

for %%G in (*.mkv) do (
%ff% -hide_banner -ss %sec% -y -i "%%G" -vframes 1 -an !fjpeg!
)

for %%I in (*.mkv) do (
set fname="%%~nxI"
set title="%%~nI"
set audio="AAC Surround 5.1"
set fout="%%~nI_audio_new.mkv"
call :runFF !fname! !title! !audio! !fout!
del /q *.jpg
pause
goto :eof
)

:runFF
%ff% ^
-y ^
-i "%~1" ^
-attach "!fjpeg!" ^
-map_metadata 0 ^
-map_chapters 0 ^
-metadata title="%~2" ^
-map 0:0 -metadata:s:v:0 language=eng -metadata:s:s:0 language=eng -metadata:s:s:0 title="English" -metadata:s:t:0 filename="!fjpeg!" -metadata:s:t:0 mimetype="image/jpeg" ^
-map 0:1 -metadata:s:a:0 language=eng -metadata:s:a:0 title="%~3" ^
-c:v copy ^
-c:a ac3 -b:a 640k -ac 6 ^
"%~4"
exit /b
```

Original post below:

I figured out you can combine the different `-map` streams. So I took `-map 0:0` and combined it with `-map 0:3` and left `-map 0:2` to decode the audio stream I wanted.

Here is a working script that fits my question.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
prompt $g
color 0a

pushd "%~dp0"

set FF=C:\MAB\local64\bin-video\ffmpeg.exe

:: create cover art jpg file
for %%G in (*.mkv) do (
%FF% -hide_banner -ss 30 -y -i "%%G" -vframes 1 -an Cover.jpg
)

:: run ffmpeg x265
for %%I in (*.mkv) do (
set TITLE=%%~nI
set fname="%%~nxI"
set fout="%%~nI(1080p).mkv"
call :runff !fname! !fout!
del /s /q *.jpg
pause
goto:eof
)

:runff
%FF% ^
-y ^
-i "%~1" ^
-attach "Cover.jpg" ^
-map_metadata 0 ^
-map_chapters 0 ^
-metadata title="%TITLE%" ^
-map 0:0 -metadata:s:v:0 language=eng -metadata:s:s:0 language=eng -metadata:s:s:0 title="English" -metadata:s:t:0 filename="Cover.jpeg" -metadata:s:t:0 mimetype="image/jpeg" ^
-map 0:2 -metadata:s:a:0 language=eng -metadata:s:a:0 title="Surround 5.1 (DTS)" ^
-c:v libx265 -preset medium -crf 20 -vf "scale=1920:-1" -threads 0 ^
-c:a ac3 -b:a 640k -ac 6 ^
"%~2"
exit /b
```

Comment: You can stream selectors, such as `-map 0:a:0`, to choose the first audio stream instead of having to know or guess the absolute mapping address which may vary between inputs.

Comment: I will take a look into this. Thanks.